# Apple Home Sharing on a Linux machine

Tags: networking, media, shared-library

Is it possible to share a directory with media files to an Apple TV (Gen 2 & 3) using Home Sharing on a Linux machine? I've found some solutions suggesting DAAP but none of them seems to be for video or Apple TV.

- http://linuxhomeserverguide.com/mediaserver/firefly.php
- [iTunes DAAP server setup on Debian Linux - LinuxConfig.org](http://linuxconfig.org/itunes-daap-server-setup-on-debian-linux)

I would prefer a native solution instead of for example running iTunes through Wine.

Comment: This is one of the advantages of running Mac OS X on the desktop instead of Linux. :)

Comment: What media file formats, specifically? Are you expecting this to work with "protected" iTunes Store content?

Comment: No, it's my own files. mp4 and m4v.

Answer (score 1):

The [Firecore aTV Flash Black](http://firecore.com/atvflash-black) firmware may work for you.

I say "may" because:

1. I haven't tried it.
2. You aren't being specific about codecs and such.
3. Although the firmware is supposed to be compatible with several types of media servers, you may or may not be able to find one that works in your particular situation.

Beware, the "4½ mice" review score they so proudly display is for a much older version of the firmware. [That review](http://www.macworld.com/article/1145656/atvflash4_review.html) is for the firmware that ran on the old aluminum-body Apple TVs.